# IIS unselects a SSL certificate from a Site Binding

Tags: ssl, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

Once per month, IIS unselects a SSL certificate from a Site Binding each few weeks, one of our site bindigs looses the SSL certificate. It appears as "Not selected".

It is a Windows Server 2012R with IIS8. We have installed three sites and one of them has 6 different Site Bindings with SSL certificates generated with LetsEncrypt and acme-win-simple.

This problem happens in only one of them. The SSL certificate is good, not  expired yet; actually the solution is to drop-down the menu and select again the certificate.

The server has not restarted.

I know that it is a generic question, but any help, recommendation or hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your best resource is Microsoft support. Open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com and they can help analyze. Of course, if you happen to hit typical cases like https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saurabh_singh/2010/05/11/ssl-bindings-are-randomly-getting-deleted-for-a-website-with-error-ssl-certificate-settings-deleted-for-port-x-x-x-x443-in-the-event-logs-iis-7-07-5/ you can apply the workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description, see this [GitHub Issue thread](https://github.com/PKISharp/win-acme/issues/692), they have explained the same scenario; what you have explained, if its right we can investigate further.

If its related to renewals, its better to use [Certify for Lets Encrypt](https://certifytheweb.com/) - GUI tool